# customvalidator based on visibility of control

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have the custom validator code

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ddl1" ClientValidationFunction="IscontrolVisible" ControlToValidate="ddl1"
                            runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValSummary" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="drop down invisible">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

below is the function

```
 function IscontrolVisible(source, arguments) {
        //if ((document.getElementById(source).visibility == "visible")) {
        debugger;
        if (arguments.value == "" || arguments.value == "Select...") {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

how can i get the error message based on the visibility of the control?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `source.controltovalidate` property to get the ID of the control being validated, so use `document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate)` in your code.

However, you will only be able to detect whether the control you are validating on is visible **if** you are directly setting the visibility **on** the control itself.

In which case, you can do something like one of the following...

```
if (document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate).style.visibility !== "false") {
if (document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate).style.display !== "none") {
```

If the control is not visible because of one of it's parent controls, then it does NOT inherit the CSS styling of `visibility` or `display`.  In which case you would have to recursively check all the ancestors of the control in question.

**Additional**

If you want to change the ErrorMessage text (note this will only change it locally on the browser, and will NOT be replicated back on the server after a postback), then the following should work for the validation summary message box popup and list/bullets...

```
source.errormessage = "New Error Message";
```

And the following should work for the message when shown as part of the validator itself...

```
source.innerHTML = "New Error Message";
```